# Converting ascii formatted tables to rtf

Tags: macos, bash, text, replace, applescript

I have a bunch of really old texts in plain ascii. The majority of the text are simple tables formatted as next:

```
------------------------------------------
| Some text         |  200.3 | some text |
------------------------------------------
| Another text      |  30.30 | comment   |
------------------------------------------
...many "lines" like above...
```

I need convert the text into "modern" document. Copying manually the cells into the TextEdit.app tables is really painfull job. (I'm using OS X).

Is here some possibility with some scripting how to convert the tables into RTF or DOC format? I can try make the script myself, only need some ideas how to start...

Answer (score 3):

I love apple-automator services, so i show you the whole workflow - with the next steps:

- Start Automator.app
- Select `Service`
- Set Receives *rich text*
- and *check* the `Output replaces selected text` checkbox
- Click "Show library" on the toolbar (if hidden)

Now add the 1st action:

- `Run shell script`
- Pass input: `to stdin`
- change the Shell to: `/usr/bin/perl`

add the following script

```
use 5.012;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
print "<table border='1'>\n";
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    next if /^\s*[=-]*\s*$/;
    my @arr = m/(?:^|\G\|)((?:[^\\|]|\\.)*)/sg;
    print "<tr><td>" . join('</td><td>', map {s/^\s*(.*?)\s*$/$1/;$_} splice(@arr,1,-1)) . "</td></tr>\n";
}
print "</table>";
```

now the second action:

- `Run shell script`
- Pass input: `to stdin`

add the next script

```
textutil -stdin -inputencoding UTF-8 -format html -convert rtf -stdout | pbcopy -Prefer rtf
```

and add the third action:

- `Get content of the clipboard`

Save the service with some name, like: `Table2Rtf`

Workflow:

- simply start your TextEdit.app,
- load you ascii file
- change the type of the document to RTF (Menu: Format -> Make Rich text)
- select the "ascii table" (make sure than you select the whole table with the all `|` characters)
- and from the `TextEdit -> Services` run the above service.

If all going OK - the table is replaced with an simple RTF table, you can adjust column widths, etc....

The actions do:

- the `perl` script convert the text table into an simple HTMLtable
- the `textutil` converts the HTML into RTF and copy the rtf into the clipboard
- the last is get the rtf clipboard contents
- and because is selected the "Output replaced the input" - the result RTF simply replaces the text based table inplace in the document.
- you can save the "rtf" as "doc" too.

Mac's `Automator.app` is very powerful, with some tweaking you can make an `converor.app` and simple drop into it all your ascii files for converting into rtf files.

Comment: Don't bother about it. If your inputs are ascii - the utf8 will works without problems.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a small Python script to convert this to, say, html, I guess.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, re

print '<html><body><table><tr>'
for line in sys.stdin:
  if re.match(r'^-+$', line):  # separator line?
    print "</tr><tr>"
  else:  # line with values
    print ''.join('<td>%s</td>' % field for field in line.split('|'))
print '</tr></table></body></html>'
```

Answer (score 0):

If the text is reliably separated with '|' chars for each field, the awk language will prove to be a good tool to "boil down" your information :-)

```
  awk '-F|' -v OFS="\t" 'NF>1{ print $2, $3, $4 )' infile > outfile.tab
```

Personally, I've haven't had to mess with RTF format in more than 10 years. Why do you think it is "modern" ;-)?  .. As you say you have "many lines like above", maybe you should think about storing this information where is more easily searchable or re-factorable, like a database? or at least some sort of spreadsheet app. But we'd more details about your intentions to make meaningful comments.

If you find this solution helpful, there are 1000's of posts here on S.O. showing similar usages of awk.

IHTH.